# Having trouble in creating css 5-star ratings

Tags: html, css

Here's what I have tried.  I want 5- stars and am getting the 2nd and subsequent stars overlaid on 1st star.  Please help.  Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m3Yw8/1/

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="star blankstar" id="outer">★</div>
  <div id="inner">
  <div style="width:50%;" class="star goldstar">★</div>
</div>
</div>
/*need 2nd star next to 1st star.*/
<div id="container">
 <div class="star blankstar" id="outer">★</div>
<div id="inner">
   <div style="width:50%;" class="star goldstar">★</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/m3Yw8/3/

Comment: Getting 5-star rating is always hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

place the inner stars inside the outer stars and use `position:relative` for the outer ones

http://jsfiddle.net/m3Yw8/5/

btw. you should use classes instead of ids if you have more than one! ids are meant to be unique in the whole document. This includes container, inner and outer

Answer (score 1):

give something a left margin

i changed your fiddle CSS for container to this, for instance

```
#container {
float: left;
margin: 1em;
}
```

Comment: It worked, it just added little margin,  I can only select 1 answer.  I have chosen Ria's answer.

Comment: :) ria's answer is more helpful than mine... it tells you about using classes instead of ids

Comment: thanks :) was just a point I noticed while debugging. But using float is of course still correct (and I did it too as you might notice ;) )